# What can I use to program a basic game in Python?

Tags: python

I've just started to program games, but I want a 3D game engine for Python like Phaser for Javascript. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines

Comment: I put it on here because some are not available on the raspberry pi.

Comment: I'd think any of the free/open source ones at the top which have linux as a target platform will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try PyGame, people have made 3D projects with that, and is ran in python.**

http://pygame.org